# How to move up values in specific columns as long as possible?

Tags: python, pandas

My input is this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['class_a',
  'class_a',
  'class_a',
  'class_a',
  'class_b',
  'class_b',
  'class_c',
  'class_c',
  'class_d'],
 'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', '', '', 'id4', 'id5', '', 'id6'],
 'name': ['abc1', '', '', 'abc2', 'abc3', '', '', 'abc4', 'abc5']})

print(df)

     class   id  name
0  class_a  id1  abc1
1  class_a  id2      
2  class_a  id3      
3  class_a       abc2
4  class_b       abc3
5  class_b  id4      
6  class_c  id5      
7  class_c       abc4
8  class_d  id6  abc5
```

And I need to have one single row per pair (class/id). We need to move up the values in `id` and `name` as long as it's possible.

```
     class   id  name
0  class_a  id1  abc1
1  class_a  id2  abc2
2  class_a  id3      
3  class_b  id4  abc3
4  class_c  id5  abc4
5  class_d  id6  abc5
```

I tried with the code below but I get a messed up result :

```
df.replace('',np.nan,inplace=True)
df.groupby(['class', 'id'], as_index=False, sort=False).first()

     class   id  name
0  class_a  id1  abc1
1  class_a  id2  None
2  class_a  id3  None
3  claas_b  id4  None
4  class_c  id5  None
5  class_d  id6  abc5
```

Can you provide an explanation please ?

Comment: If `class_d` has no values in input DataFrame, should be removed in final DataFrame?

Comment: Suppose we have a `class_e` with empty id and empty name, it should be not removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with sorting by `key` parameter for correct ordering, then reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and last remove empty rows if exist at least one value:

```
out = (df.melt('class').sort_values('value', key=lambda x: x.eq(''))
         .assign(g = lambda x: x.groupby(['class','variable']).cumcount())
         .pivot(index=['class','g'], columns='variable', values='value')
         .droplevel(1)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))


cols = out.columns.difference(['class'])
out = out[out[cols].ne('').any(axis=1) | ~df['class'].duplicated(keep=False)]
print (out)
     class   id  name
0  class_a  id1  abc1
1  class_a  id2  abc2
2  class_a  id3      
4  class_b  id4  abc3
6  class_c  id5  abc4
8  class_d  id6  abc5
9  class_e
```

Input DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['class_a',
  'class_a',
  'class_a',
  'class_a',
  'class_b',
  'class_b',
  'class_c',
  'class_c',
  'class_d',
  'class_e'],
 'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', '', '', 'id4', 'id5', '', 'id6',''],
 'name': ['abc1', '', '', 'abc2', 'abc3', '', '', 'abc4', 'abc5','']})

print(df)
     class   id  name
0  class_a  id1  abc1
1  class_a  id2      
2  class_a  id3      
3  class_a       abc2
4  class_b       abc3
5  class_b  id4      
6  class_c  id5      
7  class_c       abc4
8  class_d  id6  abc5
9  class_e
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to drop the NaNs and reindex:

```
out = (df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('class')  # replace '' by NaN
         # push the non-NaNs on top          
         .transform(lambda s: (s2:=s.dropna()).set_axis(s.index[:len(s2)]))
         # remove empty rows
         .dropna(how='all')
         # add original grouper back
         .join(df[['class']], how='left')
      )
```

Output:

```
     class   id  name
0  class_a  id1  abc1
1  class_a  id2  abc2
2  class_a  id3   NaN
4  class_b  id4  abc3
6  class_c  id5  abc4
8  class_d  id6  abc5
```

To keep loner classes, just change the method to remove the empty rows and keep those that only had NaNs initially with help of [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
out = (df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('class')
         .transform(lambda s: (s2:=s.dropna()).set_axis(s.index[:len(s2)]))
         .join(df[['class']], how='left')[list(df)]
         .loc[lambda x: x.drop(columns='class').notna().any(axis=1)
                     | ~x['class'].duplicated(keep=False)]
      )
```

Output:

```
     class   id  name
0  class_a  id1  abc1
1  class_a  id2  abc2
2  class_a  id3   NaN
4  class_b  id4  abc3
6  class_c  id5  abc4
8  class_d  id6  abc5
9  class_e  NaN   NaN
```